# Combining rows in attribute tables in QGIS 3.4 with some strings that should be added together and others left untouched

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want to do the following with some fields in the attribute table but I have no idea how to do it:
Each row is about a parcel and its selling price, it also contains its address, cadastral ID etc.
The problem is that sometimes, one sale included several parcels, in this case the total price of the sale is included in each parcel row. As I would like to get the price/sqm of the land sale, it obviously gets some wrong result since the price is for all the parcels in one sale, not each individual parcel.

For instance, some land was sold for 1000 euros (just for the sake of explanation). The land is located 1, Olive Street. This land includes 3 parcels A, B and C with 300, 200 and 100 sqm respectively for a total of 600 sqm. In this case, the table of attributes look like this:

```
Parcel_A | 300 | 1000 | 1 | Olive Street

Parcel_B | 200 | 1000 | 1 | Olive Street

Parcel_C | 100 | 1000 | 1 | Olive Street
```

Right now if I just do 1000/300 = 3,3 euros/sqm this is of course wrong since 1000 euros is the total price of this piece of land which includes parcels A, B and C.

I would like to transform the previous table and arrive at the following result :

`Parcel_A_Parcel_B_Parcel_C | 600 | 1000 | 1 | Olive Street | 1,66` (1,66 being the price/sqm of the total piece of land).

I guess I have to do something like this (just in terms of logic) : if the address (street name and street number) is the same, concatenate Parcel Name field, add area, keep just one instance (any instance since they will be similar) of area, street name and street number. And then (ideally), replace the original rows by the resulting row (since I won't need the "old" rows anymore).
Also, in case a piece of land only includes one parcel, it should of course keep it in place since there is no issue in this case.

How do I use the field calculator to perform this kind of thing (if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

It would group the records by civic number + street name (though if you can group by ID do so), union the geometries, sum the area and do the division using this sum.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Feel free to add more fields from your layer, and to adjust the names!

```sql
SELECT group_concat(name,'_') as new_name,
       st_union(geometry) as geometry, 
       sum(parcel_area) tot_area, 
       min(total_price) as total_price, 
       1.0*min(total_price)/sum(parcel_area) as price_per_area_unit,
       civic_number,
       street_name
FROM myLayer
GROUP BY civic_number, street_name
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, I'm going to try it now, thank you so much! Why do you use "min" here? I see that it means "minimum" but doesn't it apply to numbers only? Or does it say to just use one string among many similar strings?

Comment: And I was also wondering about the 1.0*min. Thank you!

Comment: Because we aggregate, we must either use the field in the group by (like the street name) or apply a function to keep/construct a single output. Here it is the same value in every record, so we can keep the min, the max, the mean etc, it doesn't matter. It is applied on the price field, which is (should!) a number

Comment: If you divide 2 integers, the output is an integer. By multiplying by 1.0 first, it makes the computation to use floats and therefore will output digits

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried your formula and it worked perfectly! At first my layer didn't have underscores in the name between the different words but after I renamed it with underscores it was ok. I also tried with "create a virtual layer" instead of "add/edit" one but it didn't work in this case, I'm not sure why. In any case this is really a great feature, thank you again!

Comment: I was wondering about something: how would you do if you have several pieces of land (or retail units for instance) and I want to do a virtual layer where the area of all the retail units with the same sales ID is summed? For instance, I have units A, B and C which are part of sale 1, and units D, E and F that are part of sale 2 and I would like to have just 2 rows, one for sale 1 (where the total combined area of A+B+C would be displayed) and one for sale 2 (with the combined area of D+E+F). Something like : if sale id is the same, sum all areas. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: you can change the `group by` clause to be `sale_id` instead of the address components